Component declared in a parent module not visibile inside a component rendered by ng-template
I have an app written in Angular 12.2.16 and I need to implement some components.
This specific part is about LayoutLoader (component+module)
In layout-loader/layout-loader.component.html there is <ng-template #content></ng-template> that render one of the templates under the ./layouts folder
I added a new template under layout-loader/layouts/lista1livello-layout
If I put this code (that call some other components) in lista1livello-layout.component.html and it works:
<uni-base-loader-layout title="asdasda" theme="in-page">
  <ng-container loader>
    <uni-loading [loading]="false">
      <uni-cards-loader
        [data]="results"
        columns="2"
        theme="in-page"
      ></uni-cards-loader>
    </uni-loading>
  </ng-container>
</uni-base-loader-layout>

Than I need to render two separate components so in lista1livello-layout.component.html I put <ng-template #content></ng-template> and I can render another component under layout-loader/layouts/lista1livello-layout/layouts/lista1livello-search with some text.
If instead in lista1livello-search.component.html I put the code with the loading card I can't compile it. Angular doesn't recognize the uni-* components.
I'm tried to add the modules as import in another modules but I failed.

currently the question is confusing, please explain a bit more with screenshot showing the issue. A stackblitz that replicates the issue you are facing is best for everyone to debug

It's a very complex app, I tried to narrow down the problem.
I'll add a screenshot of the structure of the files and the compiling error

I have inserted in the module layout-loader.module.ts the component that caused the compilation not to work, I also added the component in which that component is used in the declarations and exports array of the layout-loader.module.ts so that components can use the imports declared
layout-loader.module.ts:
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    LayoutLoaderComponent,
    ...entryComponents,
    FallbackLayoutComponent,
    Lista1LivelloLayoutComponent, //added the component I wrote
    Lista1LivelloSearchComponent, //added the component I wrote
    Lista1LivelloAreaComponent, //added the component I wrote
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    PartialModule,
    ChipModule,
    PipesModule,
    PageIndexModule,
    EditorModule,
    PartialModule,
    LocationCardModule,
    MapModule,
    StudyPlanModule,
    ShareModule,
    LinkDownloadModule,
    LayoutComponentsLoaderModule,
    FontAwesomeModule,
    BaseLoaderLayoutModule,
    LoadingModule,
    CardsLoaderModule,
    GestitoDaModule,
    SearchInputModule, // added the component used in my components
  ],
  exports: [
    LayoutLoaderComponent,
    ...entryComponents,
    Lista1LivelloLayoutComponent,  //added the component I wrote
    Lista1LivelloSearchComponent,  //added the component I wrote
    Lista1LivelloAreaComponent,  //added the component I wrote
  ],
})

